# Web framework in pure SQL

Tags: sql, frameworks, web

I heard that SQL is Turing complete language (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7580013/2604170) I am just curious if would be possible to create independent web framework like Ruby on rails or Flask (Python) in pure SQL (SQL would replace python or ruby or java for example)

It's just idea, but I think it would be really interesting if something like this could work.

I apologize, if it's stupid question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://youtu.be/0_PK1eDQyVg

Comment: sounds interesting, I am just curious how fast it is.

Comment: Do you mean like https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Application_Express

Comment: yep, but I am not sure, that's pure SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because you need at least basic IO capabilities to be able to serve up web content. Assuming you finesse that by using something else to put in front of your database server then, yes, technically that would be possible. It would just be horrible.